# How to eliminate excess vertical space when a line breaks in mobile view

Tags: html, css

My html has a "headline" with font-size: 1.7em and line-height 1.8em and no margins specified.
It works great on a desktop computer or a phone, except when the length of the text forces a line break in mobile view. Then  there is way too much vertical space between the top words and bottom words in the broken line.
It's like this:

**First Words Followed by Last Words**

that works great on desktop. But on mobile it comes out like this

**First Words Followed



by Last Words**

When what I need is

**First Words Followed

by Last Words**

I tried reducing line-height and adding margins like this, but it doesn't seem to help.

```
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
line-height: .5em;
font-size: 1.7em;
```

Again, everything is fine, except when the text is too long to fit in a single line in a mobile view. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Are you not using a heading tag such as `<h1>` for the headline that has default block margins and increased font size and weight? What are you trying to achieve with the line height or margins?

Comment: This is because you have to use line-height 1.8em that will be too much when word wrap so if you want to use this much line-height then you need to change the line height value for mobile screen or when word-wrap by placing media query.

Comment: Thank you, Tim R. I'm building a file that gets imported into a WordPress site, and when I added style to standard tags, it was interfering with the site's css. So, I was just making <div>'s with whatever styling I needed.
duh! I made a class for color, alignment, font-weight and assigned it to my <h2 class='special'> and everything is wonderful.